# How can i make background image to have always 100% width and height in his container without using background-size:cover

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have this layout

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row bg no-gutters justify-content-center align-items-center text-justify">
        <div class="col-md-4 our-mission my-5 p-3">
            <h3 class="text-right mx-2">Our mission</h3>
            <p class="mx-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero iure alias, error voluptate nam pariatur temporibus perferendis voluptas voluptatum quas natus autem officia assumenda velit hic distinctio inventore deserunt dolorum?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 our-vision my-5 p-3">
            <h3 class="mx-2">Our vision</h3>
            <p class="mx-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero iure alias, error voluptate nam pariatur temporibus perferendis voluptas voluptatum quas natus autem officia assumenda velit hic distinctio inventore deserunt dolorum?</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container-fluid {
    padding:0px !important;
}


.bg {
    background-image: url("../../../assets/about-us-blue-background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border:2px solid blue;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.our-mission {
    background-color: var(--mainColor);
    border-radius: 30px 0px;
}

.our-vision {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 0px 30px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .our-vision {
        bottom: 0px;
    }

    .our-vision, .our-mission {
        /* margin: 0px 17px; */
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .our-vision, .our-mission {
        margin: 0px 17px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

.our-mission, .our-vision {
    position: relative;
    color: var(--textColor);
}

.our-mission-text {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 20px;
}

.our-vision-text {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

so i have two boxes with some header and text and that boxes are having parent with class -bg
with which through css i am inserting background image inside.

If i don't use  background-size: cover; then the image don't take always 100 width and height and on smaller devices my image is not taking the last 'edge' at the bottom - so don't have full height 100%.
To solve this problem i am using

```
 background-size: cover;
```

and now my background image has always 100width and height but the quality of the image itself is reduced a lot.

My question is how can i make my background image to take always 100% width and height, without using background-size:cover so i can preserve it's quality ?

**what i tried**

I tried adding

```
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
```

on the `bg` class but that didn't solved my problem

Comment: give me link your project

Comment: Why you need the link Vladimir?

Comment: Do you need help? if yes, then I need to look at your code and how it looks Visually

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to preserve quality, no matter how you stretch your image to full width/height.
As soon as your image is smaller than your screen, you will always loose quality because it is like you are zooming into the pixels.

Maybe you should consider using images with higher resolution?
If file size is a problem, you could try it with WebP image format.
According to [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/webp) it's already supported by most of modern browsers.

Comment: Hello Hoargarth.You say when the image has bigger width and height, and i use background-size cover - then as the image has bigger resolution it will be "cleaner" after background-size cover then the image with smaller resolution ?

Comment: The thing is, if you use `background-size: cover`, the image will always be stretched or squeezed into the container. So if you container is larger than the image, the Image will be scaled up. This results in "pixelated" parts of the image. But if it is the other way around, large image and small container, then the image gets scaled down. Scaling down may result in some artifacts as well, but less noticable than scaling up. -- In general what I'm doing is: Use the container size for the image as well and double de resolution. Container = 100px * 100px -> Image = 200px * 200px

Comment: Doubling the image resolution keeps the image from scaling up on retina displays (for example on MacBooks)

Comment: And keep in mind, `cover` will not keep aspect ration of images